# TestFlight crash log not showing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, crash-reports

Ok. I am on the latest version of Xcode, macOs, everything is updated. I just uploaded a new build to TestFlight and all of a sudden no crash reports are showing up in Organizer.

I know we had a crash because my tester showed me his phone - I had him go to Privacy settings and turn on the "share Analytics with developers" option, just as Apple says in their documentation.

This is what I see, despite multiple crashes from one of my testers and after waiting over 9 hrs for it too come through:

[image]

The odd thing is my last build generated full crash reports, which was great. I just retired that build, but the new build is not generating reports.

This is my scheme settings if that changes anything, I am new to test flight crash testing:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check the Console app and filter with "Xcode" for errors

Answer (score 0):

I found that for me, the crash logs were not showing up in Xcode. However, if I completely exit Xcode and then re-open it the crash logs appeared. Not sure why this is. So to see my  crash logs I had to:

- Fully exit Xcode (Quit Xcode from the Xcode menu)
- Reopen your project in Xcode
- Go to `Window > Organizer`
- Select the `Crashes` tab
- You should now be able to select your appropriate build number from the drop down menu
- Your crashes should now show up.

Keep in mind there may be a slight delay between when Apple receives it and when they show up in Xcode.